# Representing closeness among elements of a double vector

Tags: math

I have a double vector:

```
r = -50 + (50+50)*rand(10,1)
```

Now i want to ideally have all the numbers in the vector equal upto a tolerance of say `1e-4`. I want to represent each `r` with a scalar say `s(r)` such that its value gives an idea of the quality of the vector. The vector is high quality if all elements in the vector are equal-like. I can easily run a `for` loop like

```
for i=1:10
 for j=i+1:10
  check equality upto the tolerance
 end
end
```

But even then i cannot figure what computation to do inside the nested for loops to assign a scalar representing the quality . Is there a better way such that given any vector `r` length `n`, i can quickly calculate a scalar representing the quality of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double-loop algorithm is somewhat slow, of order O(n**2) where n is the number of dimensions of the vector. Here is a quick way to find the closeness of the vector elements, which can be done in order O(n), just one pass through the elements.

Find the maximum and the minimum of the vector elements. Just use two variables to store the maximum and minimum so far and run once through all the elements. The difference between the maximum and the minimum is called the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics)) of the values, a commonly accepted [measure of dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) of the values. If the values are exactly equal, the range is zero which shows perfect quality. If the range is below `1e-4` then the vector is of acceptable quality. The bigger the range, the worse the equality.

The code is obvious for just about any given language, so I'll leave that to you. If the fact that the range only really considers the two extreme values of the vector bothers you, you could use other measures of variation such as the interquartile range, variance, or standard deviation. But the range seems to best fit what you request.